# Modifying Iterator to Display the Elements in the Order they were Received

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, key, iterable

I'm having difficulty printing elements out in the order they were entered.  My program is reading a .txt file.

I'm using a Queue to store the elements which I thought was a FIFO. But when I run my program I get the elements in reverse order.  I thought I'd try a Priority Que but instead I was rewarded with an alphabetically sorted order.

If anyone has any ideas or directions I should go to find the answer I'd really appreciate it.  Thanks.

```
public Iterable<Key> keys()  
{
    Queue<Key> queue = new Queue<Key>();

    for (Node x = first; x != null; x = x.next)

   queue.enqueue(x.key);

    return queue;
}
```

Comment: Tried a `LinkedList`?

Comment: you need a `Deque` (double ended queue) implementation

Comment: Deque structure using the method pollFirst() worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the poll() method of the queue should return the head element in a first in first out way.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ReturnQueue 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Queue<Integer> myQueue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    myQueue.add(12);
    myQueue.add(8);
    myQueue.add(9);
    myQueue.add(10);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    System.out.println(myQueue.poll());
}
}
```

this returns 12 8 9 10 on different lines, in the order they were added.

Comment: It worked great using the Deque data structure with the pollFirst() method.  Thanks!